# Python socket and scapy sniff drop udp packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp, scapy

Windows 10. Python 3.7.8. Scapy 2.4.5
I need to transfer several megabytes of data. For example, I use socket this way:

Transceiver:

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "192.168.13.172"
UDP_PORT = 0x1111
MESSAGE = b"... 1000 bytes data ..."
print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for x in range(0, 1500):
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

And receiver:

```
import socket
import select

UDP_IP = "192.168.13.172"
UDP_PORT = 0x1111
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.setblocking(0)

total = b''
while True:
    reads, send, excepts = select.select([sock], [], [], 8)
    if reads:
        data, adr = sock.recvfrom(4000000)
        total += data
        print(len(total))
        if len(total) >= 1500000:
            break
    elif send:
        print(send)
    elif excepts:
        print(excepts)
    else:
        print('timeout')
        break
```

Receiver output:

```
162000
163000
164000
timeout
```

But Transceiver sent 1500000 bytes. I saw them all in the Wireshark log. Where are other 1500000 - 164000 = 1336000 data bytes?

Also I used scapy like this:

```
data = sc.sniff(lfilter=lambda r: sc.UDP in r and sc.IP in r and r[sc.IP].src == ip_address, timeout=8)
```

And scapy also drops some packets. What I need to do to get all sent packets?

Answer (score 0):

UDP is an unreliable protocol.  If you send too much data too fast, it can overflow buffers in the implementation and drop packets.  You can see this if you number the packets sent and compare them to the number of packets received.  The following code shows this.

```py
import socket
import select
import threading

UDP_IP = 'localhost'
UDP_PORT = 0x1111

def sender():
    with socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        for x in range(1500):
            # message is 4-byte packet number repeated
            sock.sendto(x.to_bytes(4,'big') * 250, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

def receiver():
    with socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
        sock.setblocking(0)

        count = 0
        while True:
            reads, send, excepts = select.select([sock], [], [], 1)
            if reads:
                data, adr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
                number = int.from_bytes(data[:4],'big')
                print(count, number)
                if count != number:
                    break
                count += 1

            else:
                print('timeout',count)
                break

threading.Thread(target=receiver).start()
sender()
```

Output (with print, may vary):

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
 .
 .
250 250
251 251
252 252
253 262           (dropped packets here)
```

Interestingly, commenting out the `print` and just doing the comparison in the receiver allows it to keep up, at least on my system.

Output (without print)

```
timeout 1500
```

If you want reliability, use TCP not UDP.  UDP can also receive packets out-of-order, so expect to implement packet numbering and a way to request resend of dropped packets and re-order if necessary.